# How to mute sound effects in pavucontrol?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've been playing with PulseAudio.

There is a nice GUI `pavucontrol` which shows volume sliders to adjust the volume of my sinks, however it has no manual page and when I use one of the sliders it makes loud popping noises - not a bug, but some kind of pre-recorded sound effect. How do I turn these off?

Answer (score 4):

go to Pulseaudio Volume Control Playback tab:

`pavucontrol -t 1`

Set level for 'System Sounds' to 0% and/or click mute button on right

Comment: Have you tested that this works for you? I actually can't verify it, because I can't get the sounds to come back on for some reason. But I noticed that the "System Sounds" slider in pavucontrol was already muted when I launched it. I kind of think that it must have already been muted during my experiment, although maybe it got muted in response to `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false`...

Comment: turning off system sounds has been one the usual post-install adjustments for a few years for me (mostly on XFCE). can confirm it works by turning it back on and hear sounds again

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$ pacmd list-samples
```

I found out that the sample is called "audio-volume-change", here: `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga`.

You'd think that this command would work:

```
$ pacmd remove-sample "audio-volume-change"
```

but `pavucontrol` loads the sample back again not only when it starts up, but even every time you adjust the slider.

So I tried this instead, it's a bit of a hack but works for now:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo{,.moved}
```

Presumably this will be a problem every time I upgrade my system, so a better solution is needed in the long term.